# Get dimensions of an image using the header info

Tags: c#, .net

Given a jpeg file (at some url)

How can I get the header info of that jpeg? specifically the height and with of it?
I dont want to download the whole file to memory, just get header info to determine height and width.

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781272/c-get-width-height-of-image-on-web-without-downloading-whole-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# get width/height of image on web without downloading whole file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781272/c-sharp-get-width-height-of-image-on-web-without-downloading-whole-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the SO link in the comment above, you may want to check out this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ReadingImageHeaders.aspx) article.  Admittedly, it is a little older, but probably gives you the information you need.

Be sure to read the comments at the bottom of the article.