# Fetch min valuable bytes of a file to get image dimensions with sharp

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, sharp

I have many images in the cloud and need to get their dimensions. For this purpose, I decided to use `sharp#metadata`.

What minimum valuable bites do I need to fetch of a file to get this information?  Or is it possible?

Types of files that I have: `.jpeg, .png, .webp, .gif`.

The code I'm using:

```js
import sharp from 'sharp';
import axios from 'axios';

async function getDimensions(src: string, mime: string): Promise<{ width: number; height: number }> {
  // TODO: get max range by mime type
  const maxRange = 1024 * 1024;
  // END TODO
  const headers = {
    Range: `bytes=${0}-${maxRange}`,
  };
  const response = await axios.get(src, {
    headers,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  });
  const data = await sharp(response.data).metadata();
  return {
    width: data.width,
    height: data.height,
  };
}
```

Comment: Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781272/c-sharp-get-width-height-of-image-on-web-without-downloading-whole-file) specifically the part about how it maybe impossible to use this trick with jpegs.

Comment: Thanks @James. It's good to know about jpeg