# C# How to know the size of file on a website

Tags: c#, filesize

I want to download a file on a website using C# and show its downloading percentage using progressBar. I know I can use the following code to get the size of a local file, but how can I know the size of file posted on a website?

```
FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(strFilePath);
int length = (int)finfo.Length;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get http:/.../File Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122853/get-http-file-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start the download, the server should send a `Content-length` header which will tell you how big the file is.

Comment: Thanks. I write <code>request.Method="HEAD"</code> and now sucessfully use the key "Content-Length" in WebHeaderCollection to get the file size.