# How to process http links?

Tags: c#, http

As you all know there is many file host websites, is there a way to process the http link of a of file on one of those sites and retrieve a result if the file exists or if the http link even exists or not. I know that maybe some of those file host websites uses their own APIs but i want a more generic way.

Edit:

So as i understand there is no file on a server, it's just that i have to read the response and read it properly. I want to ask another thing, what about redirection, does that mean if i got the response of a link that redirects to other link, i will get the final target from the response ?

Comment: You can use `HttpRequest` to make a request and read a response.  Whether the "file" exists depends on what the server sends as a response.  There really is no such thing as "files" in HTTP, only requests and responses (which contain headers and content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out if a file exist using the exists method:

```
bool System.IO.File.Exists(string path)
```

///

in order to find out if a file exist on a remove server you can try this:

```
WebRequest request;
WebResponse response;
String strMSG = string.Empty;
request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(“http://www.yoururl.com/yourfile.jpg”));
request.Method = “HEAD”;

try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
    strMSG = string.Format(“{0} {1}”, response.ContentLength,         response.ContentType);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //In case of File not Exist Server return the (404) Error
    strMSG = ex.Message;
}
```

see [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/413945.aspx/1):

Comment: This assumes the server will respond with a 404 error, or any error at all.  It might not, we don't know.  Also, this isn't very good exception handling.  There could be more useful information in the `Exception` object that you're just throwing away.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to tell if a given URL has content.

Use the

[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx)

class.

Call the url, if you receive a 200, you're good to go. A 404 exception or similar probably means the link is no good.

Or, even better way to do this is to do a HEAD http request. See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122853/c-sharp-get-http-file-size) for more info on that.