# Get Size of Image File before downloading from web

Tags: c#, .net

I am downloading image files from web using the following code in my Console Application.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(string address_of_image_file,string filename);
```

The code is running absolutely fine.

**I want to know if there is a way i can get the size of this image file before I download it.**

PS- Actually I have written code to make a crawler which moves around the site downloading image files. So I doesn't know its size beforehand. All I have is the complete path of file which has been extracted from the source of webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get http:/.../File Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122853/get-http-file-size)

Answer (score 24):

Here is a simple example you can try
if you have files of different extensions like .GIF, .JPG, etc
you can create a variable or wrap the code within a Switch Case Statement

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.OpenRead("http://someURL.com/Images/MyImage.jpg");
Int64 bytes_total= Convert.ToInt64(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"])
MessageBox.Show(bytes_total.ToString() + " Bytes");
```

Comment: This works like a charm for me, but after the third use it stops everything and crashes. I even tried calling client.Dispose() but it's not helping... Do you have any idea why that might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: client.OpenRead() opens a readable stream for the data downloaded. So it have to be closed after use. Something like this prevents your app from crashing: `using (var sr = client.OpenRead(uri)) { ... }`

Comment: When I want to download using the same webclient, should I close the Opened connection (to read the size), or what should I exactly do?

Answer (score 6):

If the web-service gives you a [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) HTTP header then it will be the image file size. However, if the web-service wants to "stream" data to you (using Chunk encoding), then you won't know until the whole file is downloaded.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code:

```
using System.Net;

public long GetFileSize(string url)
{
    long result = 0;

    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "HEAD";
    using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        if (long.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out long contentLength))
        {
            result = contentLength;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an HttpWebRequest to query the HEAD Method of the file and check the Content-Length in the response

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this answer: [C# Get http:/…/File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122984/1617130) where your question is fully explained. It's using HEAD HTTP request to retrieve the file size, but you can also read "Content-Length" header during GET request before reading response stream.

Comment: -1. Either make it comment or add summary of the link to the answer.

Comment: Question and answer in specified link need no explanation and it's difficult to add something. I don't want to copy-paste answer from original post. Anyway, thanks for the comment, I'll take it into account in the future.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO answers are expected to contain summary of a link - check [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) - "Provide context for links".