# Get Size image from link

Tags: c#

I want to check size image from url in C#.

Ex: Url: http://img.khoahoc.tv/photos/image/2015/05/14/hang_13.jpg

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079794/get-size-of-image-file-before-downloading-from-web

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download and check:

```
string image = @"http://img.khoahoc.tv/photos/image/2015/05/14/hang_13.jpg";
byte[] imageData = new WebClient().DownloadData(image);
MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
Image img = Image.FromStream(imgStream);

int wSize = img.Width;
int hSize = img.Height;
```

Comment: The MemoryStream here is not being disposed

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://img.khoahoc.tv/photos/image/2015/05/14/hang_13.jpg";);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);

stream.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Height: " + img.Height + " Width: " + img.Width);
```

Answer (score 1):

For optimization, I suggest to use [@Backs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2910943/backs) answer with [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) to download the image:

```cs
public async Task<Size> GetImageSizeFromUrl(string url)
{
    var imageData = await new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
    var imgStream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
    var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgStream);

    return new Size(img.Width, img.Height);
}
```