# limit download file size WebBrowser C# WINFORMS

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, browser, webbrowser-control

I am building a webbrowser in WINFORMS C#. I want to limit the download file size to under 25mb. Is there any way to access the download file dialog fields which pops out when a download is detected. Should I use webclient instead. Please advice.

Comment: Go with this [Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122853/c-sharp-get-http-file-size) , its same as yours

Answer (score 0):

Not easy, but you can do that by [Implementing a Custom Download Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Sample implementation is done in [The most complete C# Webbrowser wrapper control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18935/The-most-complete-C-Webbrowser-wrapper-control)

```
m_csexwbCOMLib.FileDownloadEx += new 
  ComUtilitiesLib._IUtilManEvents_FileDownloadExEventHandler(dl_FileDownloadEx);

void dl_FileDownloadEx(int dlUID, string sURL, string sFilename, 
     string sExt, string sFileSize, string sExtraHeaders, string sRedirURL, 
     ref bool SendProgressEvents, ref bool bStopDownload, ref string sPathToSave)
```