# What's the fastest way to get size of an online file [ http ]

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, size, filesize

I'm working on a YouTube Downloader, which gets sizes of all qualities available but usually that takes a very long time and sometimes it just goes like a lightning !

I wrote this Function and it's pretty good [ only sometimes as I said before ] !

```
    Uri url = new Uri("http://example.com/document.docx");
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();

    // iSize will handle the size of the file in bytes
    Int64 iSize = response.ContentLength;
```

.

**So,** Is there a faster way to do this ?  ( Put on your mind that the files which will be measured are more than eight files ) .

.

In advance, thank you so much ;

Comment: Your question has already been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122853/get-http-file-size).

Comment: @nvoigt That function in the solution is very slow !

Answer (score 1):

That completely depends on how well-behaved the HTTP server is.

The specification says that you can send a HEAD request to get response headers like `Content-Length` without serving the file.

However, many servers don't do that.

Comment: I'm going to get size from YouTube' servers

Comment: @AlaaAlrifaie - So it depends on how Google has configured their servers.  What your asking for shouldn't be fast, it also should be ran in the background, so it doesn't matter if it is slow.