# get the downloading file size in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, filesize

I designed a download manager in vb.net, but I don't know how to get file size after downloading started, or when I put the url.

I searched on internet and here, and I found the `httpwebrequest` class, 
but I don't know how does it work and how can I add it in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get file size before download it in vb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269919/get-file-size-before-download-it-in-vb)

Comment: i see that before but i don't know how to use the code `webrequest`

Comment: Use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32340260/3970387).

Comment: I See The Code, But I Don't Know How To Display The Return Value In TextBox

Comment: Use `TextBox1.Text = GetDownloadSize("http://www.foo.com/file.mp3")`

Comment: Thanks, That Was I Want

Comment: Don't forget to upvote !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function :

```
Public Function GetDownloadSize(ByVal URL As String) As Long
    Dim r As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
    r.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Head
    Using rsp = r.GetResponse()
        Return rsp.ContentLength
    End Using
End Function
```

Here's an easy example of use :

```
MsgBox(Math.Round(GetDownloadSize("http://www.foo.com/file.mp3") / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " MB")
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32340260/3970387