# Asynchronous Download total progress

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download, percentage

Well, I created a downloader that checks all files in a list and then it downloads all files.

**Example:**

**Node Class:**

```
public class Node
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string fileHash { get; set; }
    public int fileSize    { get; set; }

    public Node(string fName, string fHash, int fSize)
    {
        fileName = fName;
        fileHash = fHash;
        fileSize = fSize;
    }
}

public class Nodes : List<Node>
{
    public void Fill(string name, string hash, int size)
    {
        Add(new Node(name, hash, size));
    }
}
```

**itemsUpdate:**

```
List<Node> itemsUpdate = new List<Node>();
```

**Downloading the files:**

[**FileDownload Class**](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2u2UrtyV)

```
FileDownload fDownload;
foreach (Node n in itemsUpdate)
{
    //fDownload contains all for the async download.
    fDownload.Download(url, n.fileName);
    //Here I show the current progress
    while (fDownload.Progress != 100)
    {
        lblProgress.Text = fDownload.Progress.ToString() + "%";
    }
    lblProgress.Text = "100%";
}
```

What I want to know is how to calculate the total progress of the download.
Hope someone could help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first calculate sum of all file size, then calculate total progress each time

```
long sum = 0;
foreach(Node n in itemsUpdate)
{
    sum += n.fileSize;
}

long nodeSum = 0;
foreach (Node n in itemsUpdate)
{
    //fDownload contains all for the async download.
    fDownload.Download(url, n.fileName);
    //Here I show the current progress
    while (fDownload.Progress != 100)
    {
        lblProgress.Text = ((nodeSum + fDownload.Progress * n.fileSize)/sum).ToString() + "%";
    }
    nodeSum += n.fileSize;
}
```

Comment: It starts working and then sets lblProgress to 0% once it finishes to download one of the files in the list.
Hope you can help me to finish this.
Thanks for being helping me :).

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to loop over all the files queue in order to acquire **their total size**, and [there is a discussion about how it is made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122853/get-http-file-size).
2. Then, in download `callbacks` progress must be checked not only relatively to current file size, but relatively to **all files sizes sum**